# Integration of a complicated expression not producing a result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here is my code;

```
f = 
  Exp[-2*x^2]*(1 - Exp[-1/y])*Sqrt[2/π]*
    Sum[
      Exp[-n/y]*Exp[4*n*χ*x*Sin[θ]]*Exp[-n^2*χ^2*x*(Sin[θ])^2], 
      {n, 0, 10}];`

g = D[f, y];

f1 = g^2/f;

f2 = Integrate[f1, {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

When I evaluate the expression for `f2`, Mathematica just keeps running without producing andy result. Where may I be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you have a chance of finding a symbolic result for your integral. I think where you went astray was in not exploring the behavior of the integrand before you tried to evaluate the integral. If you had done that, I think you would have gone for a numerical analysis of `f2`'s behavior, which is quite feasible.

#### Basics

```
Clear[f, f1, f2, g]
f[x_, y_] := 
  Exp[-2*x^2]*(1 - Exp[-1/y])*Sqrt[2/π]*
    Sum[
      Exp[-n/y]*Exp[4*n*χ*x*Sin[θ]]*Exp[-n^2*χ^2*x*(Sin[θ])^2], 
      {n, 0, 10}];
g[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], y];
f1[x_, y_] = g[x, y]^2/f[x, y];
```

#### Behavior of f1

To do numerical explorations, we need to pick value the parameters; I will use χ = 1 and θ = 30 ° (I tried several value for each parameter; the values I chose give fairly typical results).

```
Block[{χ = 1, θ = 30 °},
  Plot3D[f1[x, y], {x, -3, 4}, {y, 0, 5},
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  PlotRange -> All,
  ImageSize -> 500]]
```

[image: f1Plot]

Experimentation with domain of the plot will show the rectangle given by -3 <= x <= 4 and 0 <= y, <= 5 is where all the action is. So when we build an approximation function for `f2`, there is no need to integrate over the whole real line.

#### Approximating f2

```
f2[1, 30 °] =
  Block[{χ = 1, θ = 30 °}, 
    Interpolation[Table[{y, NIntegrate[f1[x, y], {x, -3, 4}]}, {y, .5, 4, .01}]]]
```

[image: f2Interp]

```
Plot[f2[1, 30 °][y], {y, .5, 4}]
```

[image: f2plot]

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if we can demonstrate a little progress while it is working. We can use `Simplify` to sometimes make integrals a little easier. Then because you have a fraction we can use `Apart` to see if we can break this into a sum of simpler terms. Then we use `Expand` to try to really force it into separate simpler terms. Finally we use a trick to watch it in the process of doing your problem one piece at a time.

Note: You had `Sqrt[2/pi]` in your equation. Did you mean that to be `Sqrt[2/Pi]`? I assume you did.

```
f = Exp[-2*x^2]*(1 - Exp[-1/y])*Sqrt[2/Pi]*
     Sum[Exp[-n/y]*Exp[4*n*χ*x*Sin[θ]]*Exp[-n^2*χ^2*x*(Sin[θ])^2], {n,0,10}];
g = D[f, y];
f1 = g^2/f;
Map[(Print[{"int",#}];zed=Integrate[#,{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]; Print[{"=",zed}]; zed)&,
  Expand[Apart[Simplify[f1]]]]
```

The `Map` is going to take the huge sum of terms making up your integral and one term at a time show you what it is about to integrate and then the result of the integration while it is working on the next one.

Thus far mine gets through about 60 terms while I have been formatting this. It may finish. Or it may show you a really ugly integrand and take forever working on it. But at least you can see some indication of progress while it is working on your problem so that you don't have to just wonder if it is doing anything. If it does finish then the result will be a list of the result of the individual integrations and you can use `Total` to add them all up. `Length[Expand[Apart[Simplify[f1]]]]` tells me there are going to be 470 separate integrations that it will have to get through.